# Using Google Apps Script to run data from Google Form to Sheet including an automated e-mail

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form that populates a sheet. I have an apps script that then is meant to migrate that data to a second tab, in which the columns are a little different (e.g., there are two additional columns that populate an email address via formula from yet another tab). The script also intends to auto-send an email once a value in column M is set to Yes.

Here is a sample of the first tab ('Form Responses 2'). I've added the column's letters, although they're not actually in the header row.

| Timestamp (A) | Your Name (B) | Contract Recipient's Name (C) | Contract State Focus (D) | Contract Units (E) | Contract Type (F) | Contract Scope (G) | Today's Date (H) | Due Date (I) | Send the contract? (J) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2/6/2024 22:07:49 | Craig Seip | Craig Seip | FL Resiliency | 4 | Creating New Content | CSV Core Purposes | 2/6/2024 | 2/7/2024 | Yes |

As mentioned, the script aims to move this data into a separate tab ('Creator'). Here is a sample from this tab (how it **should** populate)

| Editor_Name | Editor_Email | CC_Name | CC_Email | Project Name | Number of Units | Contract Type | Scope | Deliverable | Cost | Start_Date | End_Date | Send Contract? | Contract Complete? | Contract Cross Checked? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Craig Seip | craigw@goalbookapp.com | Craig Seip | craigw@goalbookapp.com | FL.RES | 4 | Creating New Content | CSV Core Purposes | FL.RES--4 units--Creating New Content-CSV Core Purposes | $51.70 | 2/6/24 | 2/7/24 | Yes |  |  |

Fianlly, as mentioned, once that column is marked 'Yes' that the contract should be sent, an email should be automatically sent.

Now...if I manually enter the data on the spreadsheet, the email sends fine. Also, the form populates the 'Form Responses 2' tab. What I am struggling with is having the script migrate the data into the second tab ('Creator') and auto-send the email. It keeps putting the first two columns into columns 'B' and 'D', rather than 'A' and 'C', and then no other data gets migrated.

When I Debug the script, I get under Call stack 'populateFormRow @ Code:7', and Variables lists sheet, startingRow, data, and bValue >> jValue all as undefined.

This is the sheet involved: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F6eSn6ZNLGvykbAU2lBowVd7KUUe_fsMYYo1XT19U-c/edit#gid=1348989321

And here's the google form! https://docs.google.com/forms/d/134hBPq5YwIEN1SJHeMBdzzcZrfUYEhKfNv2pQucAhlU/edit

Here's Apps Script that I have:

```
function populateFormRow(sheet, startingRow, data) {
  // Assuming 'data' is a 2D array with the first inner array representing the row of data as follows: [B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I]
  // This data corresponds to columns starting from B in 'Form Responses 2', to be mapped to specified columns in 'Creator'

  // Check if data array has the expected length (at least 9 elements for B to J)
  if (data[0].length < 9) {
    Logger.log("Data array does not contain enough elements.");
    return;
  }

  // Extract individual responses for clarity
  var bValue = data[0][0]; // From Column B (to be mapped to A in Creator)
  var cValue = data[0][1]; // From Column C (to C)
  var dValue = data[0][2]; // From Column D (to E)
  var eValue = data[0][3]; // From Column E (to F)
  var fValue = data[0][4]; // From Column F (to G)
  var gValue = data[0][5]; // From Column G (to H)
  var hValue = data[0][6]; // From Column H (to K)
  var iValue = data[0][7]; // From Column I (to L)
  var jValue = data[0][8]; // From Column J (to M)

  // Set values in the 'Creator' sheet according to the specified mapping
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 1).setValue(bValue);  // B > A
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 3).setValue(cValue);  // C > C
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 5).setValue(dValue);  // D > E
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 6).setValue(eValue);  // E > F
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 7).setValue(fValue);  // F > G
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 8).setValue(gValue);  // G > H
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 11).setValue(hValue); // H > K
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 12).setValue(iValue); // I > L
  sheet.getRange(startingRow, 13).setValue(jValue); // J > M
}

function testFindNextBlankRow(){
  var nextBlankRow = findNextBlankRow(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet())
  Logger.log("nextBlankRow="+nextBlankRow)
}

function findNextBlankRow(sheet){
  // var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //int
  var currentRow = 0;
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(currentRow + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn);

  var foo = range.getValues()
  
  // Logging to ensure function starts correctly
  // Logger.log("Starting findNextBlankRow. Last row before check: " + lastRow);
  Logger.log("Starting findNextBlankRow.");


  while (true) {
    range = sheet.getRange(currentRow + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn);
    var rangeData = range.getValues();
    var isRowEmpty = (rangeData[0][0] == "")

    // Log each step to ensure the loop progresses correctly
    Logger.log("Checking row: " + currentRow);

    if(isRowEmpty){
      return currentRow;
    }

    currentRow++;
  }

  Logger.log("Next blank row found at: " + (lastRow + 1));
  return lastRow + 1;
}


function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var creatorSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Creator");
    if (!creatorSheet) {
      Logger.log("Error: 'Creator' sheet not found.");
      return; // Exit if sheet is not found
    }
    var formResponses = e.values; // This captures all the response values

    Logger.log("About to try to find the next row...")
    
    var nextBlankRow = findNextBlankRow(creatorSheet);
    nextBlankRow = nextBlankRow + 1

    Logger.log("Attempting to write to row: " + nextBlankRow);

    // Map form responses to columns starting from B
    var formDataFromUser = formResponses.slice(1);

    Logger.log("Original form data from user:")
    Logger.log(formDataFromUser);


    creatorSheet.getRange(nextBlankRow, 2, 1, formResponses.length - 1).setValues([formDataFromUser]);
    Logger.log("Data written to 'Creator' tab.");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error in onFormSubmit: ' + error.toString());
  }
}
function sendEmailOnFormSubmitOrEdit(e) {
  var sheet, row, status;
  if (e.range) { // This checks if the event object has a range property (e.g., from an onEdit trigger)
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    row = e.range.getRow();
    status = sheet.getRange(row, 13).getValue();
  } else if (e.values) { // This assumes form submission events provide values directly
    // Adjust this logic based on how your form responses are structured
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 2");
    row = sheet.getLastRow(); // Assuming the last row is the most recent submission
    status = sheet.getRange(row, 13).getValue(); // Ensure this aligns with the correct column for "status"
  } else {
    // If neither condition is met, log an error or handle accordingly
    console.log("Event object does not contain expected properties.");
    return;
  }
  if (status === 'Yes') {
    var emailB = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue(); // Email from column B
    var emailD = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue(); // Email from column D
    var nameD = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue(); // Name from column C
    var columnI = sheet.getRange(row, 9).getValue(); // Text from column I
    var columnJ = sheet.getRange(row, 10).getValue(); // Assuming this is the dollar amount
    // Format column K as a currency string
    var columnKFormatted = columnK.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});

    var dueDateM = sheet.getRange(row, 12).getValue(); // Due date from column L
    var senderB = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue(); // Sender's name from column A
    var emailBody = "Dear " + nameD + ",\n\n" +
                    "We would like to officially offer a contract with the following conditions:\n\n" +
                    columnI + "\n\n" +
                    columnJFormatted + ".\n\n\n" +
                    "The due date for your contract is " + dueDateL + "\n\n\n" +
                    "Please let me know if you have any questions.\n\n" +
                    "Thank you,\n" + senderA;
    var subject = "Contract Offer";
    var recipient = emailB + "," + emailD + ",craigw@goalbookapp.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, emailBody);
  }

function createTriggers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailOnFormSubmitOrEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailOnFormSubmitOrEdit')
      .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
      .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
}
```

Comment: Please  [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also can you edit your question that will show your exact issues. Which part of your code is the one doing it. I can see that your issue might be coming from 

populateFormRow() but I cannot see part of your code that is using that function if you are running it directly from the Apps Script it should give you the error since it is expecting a value on the parameter that it works from.

Comment: Triggers... arghh.... :) #1: Two functions (`onFormSubmit(e)` and `sendEmailOnFormSubmitOrEdit`) triggered by `onFormSubmit`; this is going to cause issues. Combine these into a single function (with a new name) and register it as a **single** installable `onFormSubmit` trigger. #2: `sendEmailOnFormSubmitOrEdit` has two triggers! (`onFormSubmit` and `onEdit`). Create a new function (with a new name) that relates ONLY to the `onEdit` activities, then register this single function as an installable `onEdit` trigger.

Comment: @Babanana sorry if I knew the part of the code that was creating the problem, I probably wouldn't be here asking the question. I included the entire script code because I don't know what I'm doing ;-)

Comment: I undestand, can you include your sample sheet so the community will have better oversight on your current project? Also to clarify your expected result is when you edit a column to "Yes" then the data will be copied to the "Creator" Sheet then should send an email? This code you have provided is the expected result for that or there are other things it handles for you?

Comment: @Babanana I've added the link to the sample sheet. And yes, that's correct, the expected result is that whether I manually edit the column M in the 'Creator" tab or whether that happens by result of a form submission, hence sending the email. This code is meant to do those things: copy the data from the first to second tab, and send the email.

Comment: Hi would you be open to this recommendation? How about when your send contract is set on "Yes" it will be transferred the creator sheet and removing it to the Form Responses. If this is not feasible with your project please let me know why.

Comment: Regarding the form: 1) why enter today's date when the Timestamp captures the date? 2) Why set "Send Contract" = Yes? Is it your intention to send the contract immediately based on the form submission, or is there some admin work/review to be done after the submission but before the contract is to be emailed?

Comment: Regarding the "Creator" Sheet: 1) What is the purpose of this sheet? is it to track the progress of the Contract after the copy has been sent? Why are values that are captured by the form set as Data validation values (this is part of your technical problem, BTW).

Comment: Regarding the email: 1) Project name: why is this value different to the value in the form; and how is this value populated? 2) What is the meaning of the "due date"?

Comment: Regarding performance: If you have noticed that the spreadsheet and/or scripts is sluggish, it is because "Creator" has 50000+ rows and eight columns that have data validation rules.. So, those rules apply to 400,000+cells.. Suggestion: delete all but @100 rows AND **delete the validation rules** in columns A, C, E, G, H & M

Comment: thanks again @Tedinoz for all your thought and ideas. Good idea re: Timestamp. THe due date really is all that's needed, upon reflection. The contract is to be sent with the form submission, I have people who will submit the form who won't have access to the sheet itself. I used data validation to minimize the risk that submitters of the form would misspell names, which then wouldn't properly trigger the formula in 'Creator' to find the email addresses. If that's what's causing so much trouble though, clearly I can work with that risk. Re: project name, not sure why dift name, i just changed.

Comment: Ok. I’ll update the answer to reflect sending the mail on submission. I’m thinking that the “calculated” fields should be populated by the script (also simplifies the sheet).

Answer (score 1):

You want to receive Form Submissions, copy them from a linked sheet to a second sheet, add some additional data and send an email.

The existing script is failing because of multiple triggers for multiple functions, and functions that combine activities to both `onFormSubmit` and `onEdit`.

The following answer consists of a single function `copytoCreatorSendEmail(e)` to be triggered by `onFormSubmit`. The function is in two parts: T

- copy a form submission to the "Creator" sheet.
- send an email.

The function doesn't contains any *special* or *advanced* processes.

---

```
// this function copies the form response to the "Creator" Sheet as a permanent record
// and send an email
// should be installed as installable onFormSubmit trigger
function copytoCreatorSendEmail(e) {
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var creatorSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Creator02");
    var responseSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 5")
    if (!creatorSheet) {
      Logger.log("Error: 'Creator' sheet not found.");
      return; // Exit if sheet is not found
    }
    // Step#1: copy data to "Creator" sheet
    var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
    var formData = responseSheet.getRange(editedRow,2,1,8).getValues()
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: About to try to find the next row on 'Creator'...")
    var creatorAVals = creatorSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues()
    var creatorALast = creatorAVals.filter(String).length
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row of content in Column A = "+creatorALast+" so the next row = "+(creatorALast+1)) 
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the source range = "+responseSheet.getRange(editedRow,2,1,8).getA1Notation()+", and the target range = "+creatorSheet.getRange((creatorALast+1),1,1,8).getA1Notation())
    // paste the form responses to Creator
    var creatorNextRow = (creatorALast+1)
    creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow,1,1,8).setValues(formData)
    Logger.log("DEBUG: Data written to 'Creator' tab.");

    // Step#2: send the email
    var emailRecipient = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 9).getValue(); // Email from column I
    var emailRecipientCC = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 10).getValue(); // Email from column J
    var emailName = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 2).getValue(); // Name from column B
    var emailDeliverable = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 11).getValue(); // Text from column K
    var emailCost = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 12).getValue(); // Assuming this is the dollar amount
    // Format column K as a currency string
    var formattedCost = emailCost.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'});
    var dueDate = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 8).getDisplayValue(); // Due date from column H
    var senderName = creatorSheet.getRange(creatorNextRow, 1).getValue(); // Sender's name from column A
    var emailBody = "Dear " + emailName + ",\n\n" +
                    "We would like to officially offer a contract with the following conditions:\n\n" +
                    emailDeliverable + "\n\n" +
                    formattedCost + ".\n\n\n" +
                    "The due date for your contract is " + dueDate + "\n\n\n" +
                    "Please let me know if you have any questions.\n\n" +
                    "Thank you,\n" + senderName;
    var subject = "Contract Offer";
    var recipient = emailRecipient + "," + emailRecipientCC + ",craigw@goalbookapp.com";
    Logger.log("DEBUG: recipient:"+recipient+"\nsubject:"+subject+"\nBody:"+emailBody)
    // MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, emailBody);

  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error in onFormSubmit: ' + error.toString());
  }
}
```

---

**Suggestions**

- Delete the final question `Send the contract?`

This field is redundant. If you want to send an email as soon as the Form submission is received, then the question is not required. If you want to send the email after you have done some admin checking, then there is no point in populating this field as "Yes" since it isn't used as a trigger.

- Design of "Creator"

Use the first N fields to reflect the submission values. This allows a simple command to copy the submission values to "Creator".

Position the calculated fields to the right of the submission values.

[image: creator]